# Please don't obstruct my "improving edit" view

Tags: support, feature-request, review-queues, suggested-edits

I usually review suggested edits on my desktop computer with a standard 1080p monitor.

Nevertheless, when I click to improve a suggested edit, if I scroll down a little, this big white banner loaded with information I already know will stick to the top of the screen:

[image: screenshot]

Notice I now have very little real estate to work in.

Can the devs please not make it sticky?

Comment: Notice `(less)` hyperlink. Won't it hide the white box?

Comment: @Shinjo Oh, thanks. At this late of the night my ADHD gets worse. But well, no, it doesn't hide it. Just make it smaller (but is still disruptive).

Comment: You can extend the editing box downwards.

Comment: I use a userscript which automatically expands the editing boxes significantly. Useful not only for edit improving, but for pretty much every other textarea as well.

Comment: @CertainPerformance: Can you share the userscript?

Comment: @PeterMortensen That part of it is basically just one CSS rule, `textarea.wmd-input, textarea#wmd-input { height: 800px; }`, I suppose you don't even need a userscript, you could use something like Stylish. ``document.head.appendChild(document.createElement('style')).textContent = `
    textarea.wmd-input, textarea#wmd-input {
      height: 800px;
    }`; `` and you can fiddle with the height as desired

Comment: It would be better if the element wasn't taken out of the document flow. It currently gets removed from the flow when it sticks to the top causing the page content to jump upwards.

Comment: Love the irony of the button at the top saying "Improving..." (and being disabled :D)

Comment: right click, inspect element, find top most element, hit the delete button on your keyboard. That's what I do with popup, background hiding fade backgrounds etc...

Comment: *"standard 1080p"*! Ha! Rookie.